Ratio of Outer cylinder volume and arc length in a pseudosphere
In cylindrical coordinates hyperbolic geodesics on a pseudosphere can be parametrized by
$$ (r,t,z)=  {a(sech~ t, t, t-\tanh t) }$$
where $t$ is polar angle starting from cusp pseudo-radius $a$.
The (half) pseudosphere yellow ( variable thickness cylinder) volume is known to be
$$ \pi  a^3/3$$ when $z$ goes to infinity.
Interestingly I find the ratio (quotient) of the enveloping annular space in the cylinder to arc length (projection shown red )
$$\frac{\int \pi (a^2-r^2) dz}{\int ds}=\frac{\int \pi (a^2-r^2)\cos^{2} ~\phi~ ds}{\int ds},~\phi=\text{tangent slope angle}$$
is in an indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ but in the limit calculates to a constant:
$$\pi a^2$$

I request you to verify this result.
Also please help in finding this ratio for the hypo and hyper pseudospheres
Conic & Hyper Pseudospheres K=-1
that I am not getting forward but have a hunch it may also be one constant... because limiting surface areas and volume are constant. Any variation of isometric mapping among the three cases seems not plausible right now.
Hope it would be an interesting geometry  problem.
